# Elements of a Jagged Array

Tags: c#, arrays, value-type, reference-type

In c#, Elements of a Jagged Array are 'Value type' or 'Reference type'?
As Jagged arrays are array of arrays, I guess it should be a reference type not a value type. Also bc reference type can have null value.

Comment: I blame C++ and Java for making this confusing >:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term jagged array means that you have an array of an array type:

```
int[][] arr;
```

`arr` here is an array whith elements of type `int[]`. So yes, this is a reference type.

And as with all reference types, if you don't initialize the `int[]` elements of the outer array, they are `null`:

```
int[][] arr = new int[50][];
Console.WriteLine(arr[0] == null ? "null" : ? "not null");
```

gives

```
null
```

---

So it is a common gotcha for beginners to try to assign something like `arr[0][0] = 5` *before* they initialize `arr[0] = new int[desiredlength];`.

Comment: Okay gotcha! So, it is just a reference type not a value type. Thanks!